# Retrieve all text content from Android Assist API

Tags: android, ellipsis

I have a method that loop through all ViewNodes from the Assist API :

```
@Override
public void onHandleAssist(Bundle data, AssistStructure structure, AssistContent content) {
    super.onHandleAssist(data, structure, content);
    mContent = "";
    mDescription = "";
    String structuredData = content.getStructuredData();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(structuredData)) {
        structuredData = structuredData.replace("\\", "");
        mContent += structuredData + " ";
    }
    Bundle extra = content.getExtras();
    ClipData clipData = content.getClipData();
    Intent intent = content.getIntent();
    Bundle intentExtra = intent.getExtras();
    Uri uri = content.getWebUri();
    if (uri != null) {
        mContent += uri.toString() + " ";
    }
    ComponentName componentName = structure.getActivityComponent();
    int nodeCount = structure.getWindowNodeCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++) {
        AssistStructure.WindowNode windowNode = structure.getWindowNodeAt(i);
        getAllContentText(windowNode.getRootViewNode(), 5);
    }
    initView();
}

private void getAllContentText(AssistStructure.ViewNode node, int levelMax) {

    if (node != null) {
        int nodeCount = node.getChildCount();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(node.getText())) {
            mContent += node.getText().toString() + " ";
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(node.getContentDescription())) {
            mDescription += node.getContentDescription() + " ";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++) {
            AssistStructure.ViewNode childNode = node.getChildAt(i);
            getAllContentText(childNode, levelMax);
        }
    }
}
```

But if a text is ellipsized, how can I get the all Text? Or if the text is a link text, can I get the url associated with it?

Comment: Hi, did you find out how to read all text ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't reference the Views of the app directly, all you've got from the **AssistStructure** is **AssistStructure.ViewNode**. The view node getText() method returns the visible text to the user.

Maybe if you find some way to reference the Window object through your **VoiceInteractionSession getContext()** method. you can cast the context to **Activity** or **Window** then call **getDecorView()** then iterate through the child views to get the full text from the TextViews.